# Switching graphics in Ubuntu ATI

Tags: drivers, ati, support

Will Switching graphics be supported in Ubuntu in the near Future ? I have a Hp dv6 with an Ati 5650 , but it only get reconiced as a Ati 4200, that means really bad performance. I read that this is beacuse this computer uses Switching graphics and this is not supported in ubuntu. Any hope that this will be fixed ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Support on HP Pavillion g4-1004tx with Intel-AMD Hybrid Graphics ](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60121/support-on-hp-pavillion-g4-1004tx-with-intel-amd-hybrid-graphics)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTI3MQ) on phoronix website, it seens that the new catalyst 11.4 will support it.