# I have an Intel GPU and a AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5400 series GPU, multiple questions

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, hp, ati, vgaswitcheroo

1. They are the supposed to be Switchable, the Hybrid Graphics page seems to be a little dated (talking about  10.10 and kernel 2.6)
2. I'm not sure the AMD MRHD is working, how can I tell which graphics card the computer is currently using? I would prefer the AMD the Intel is supposed to be the "power saving" however most of the time my laptop is plugged in
3. I installed the  "ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver" and that installed the Catalyst Control Center, however when I open the CCC it tells me

> No AMD graphics driver is installed, or the AMD driver is not functioning properly.
>   Please install the AMD driver appropriate for you AMD hardware, or configure using >aticonfig.

There is another proprietary drive available "ATI Fire GL" but when I try to install that it says

> SystemError: E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken package

Now I found the bug page on that but should the first one be sufficient?

I thought I might as well post this for you all, not sure how much help it could be

```
brendon@Brendons-Lappy:~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel>00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02
Kernel driver in use: pcieport>Kernel modules: shpchp>00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics >Controller (rev 02)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915>00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI >Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
Kernel driver in use: mei
Kernel modules: mei>00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced >Host Controller (rev 05)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd>00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition >Audio (rev 05)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel>00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root >Port >1 (rev 05)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp>00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root >Port >2 (rev 05)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp>00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced >Host Controller (rev 05)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd>00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)>00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller >(rev 05)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt>00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA >AHCI Controller (rev 05)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci>00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
Kernel modules: i2c-i801>00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset >Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
Kernel driver in use: intel ips
Kernel modules: intel_ips>01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD >5400 Series]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
Kernel modules: fglrx, radeon>01:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc Manhattan HDMI Audio [Mobility Radeon HD >5000 >Series]>>7f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic >Non-core Registers (rev 02)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a>7f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System >Address Decoder (rev 02)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a>7f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a>7f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a>7f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a>7f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144a
```

EDIT: Just letting you all know I've been using Ubuntu on and off since 7.04, and know my way basically around it, however it has changed greatly of late

Comment: see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60121/support-on-hp-pavillion-g4-1004tx-with-intel-amd-hybrid-graphics/60627#60627

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with the Mobility Radeon cards, but with HD5850 AMDs new open source drivers (radeon) works much better than the old, proprietary ones you get with the catalyst package. I would definitely use the open drivers unless you have some serious issues. The open ones are much faster and much more stable. You also never have to consider updates and stuff since they're built in.

Comment: The single AMD GPU  works, the hybrid Intel-AMD GPUs don't.