# HP Pavilion dv6 is not booting with switchable graphics

Tags: boot, radeon, fglrx, hp-pavilion, dv6

I have an HP Pavilion dv6 with switchable graphics: an integrated Intel GPU and a discrete ATI GPU (Radeon Mobility HD  6490M (1 GB DDR5)). Any attempt to use the ATI driver (either proprietary or open-source) fails because on reboot it tries to use the Intel graphics and so X fails to start up.

Normally there should be an option to disable the Switchable setting in the BIOS but HP have not allowed that set up.

Basically I'm stuck.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Support on HP Pavillion g4-1004tx with Intel-AMD Hybrid Graphics ](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60121/support-on-hp-pavillion-g4-1004tx-with-intel-amd-hybrid-graphics)

Comment: I am asuming ur ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS so please let me know if the same solution works for you !

Answer (score 1):

AMD doesn't support switchable graphics on linux: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Features. There is an independent utility called vga_switcheroo that allows switching between integrated and discrete GPUs but it requires some fiddling and a restart of Xorg for the switch to take place.

Answer (score 0):

I have Hp pavilion dv6 6155tx and my card is also 6490m so please look at
[this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450/)

If u have already installed any amd driver in any process (fglrx) then please remove it 1st by :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

If possible read all the posts. This works like a charm. One more thing please use catalyst 12.8 during the whole process. If u need to ask anything just let me know !