# Can I use fglrx if I disable my integrated graphics?

Tags: ati, fglrx, 3d, hybrid

First of all: I love the new Ubuntu-Release. Sadly, I cant really use it.
My Laptop has a i5-CPU, which comes with integrated graphics.
It seems like there is no way at the moment to change the GPU while X is running, but I'm fine with that.
Basically, I just want 3D Acceleration to play some games, but I cant get fglrx to install in any way. I tried the integrated Tool for installing such drivers, but I also tried downloading them from the AMD Website. Either way my Desktop/X11 either gets screwed up or I don't have any 3D acceleration whatsoever ( I tried different options with aticonfig ).
Unfortunately my Laptop does not have the option to disable the integrated GPU, so I cant test how the driver would react if there was only one card.

So my Question is: Is there any way to get 3D-Acceleration out of my Laptop?

( It might help to mention that vga_switcheroo is working to at least turn off the card im not currently using, but that does not enable 3D-Graphics )

Comment: What laptop do you have? Specific model plz, some BIOS allow to turn switching off, some dont, depends on model.

Comment: Acer TimelineX 3820 ; i5 M460 ; Radeon HD 5650

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/60121

Comment: Not a duplicate, the solutions cant be applied equality to both cases.

Answer (score 1):

On the TimelineX 3820 there is an option to switch from dual graphics to single graphics.

In your case you want to use the ATI card, so at your laptop's BIOS search for `Switchable` setting on graphics and change it to `Discrete`. That will make your laptop use only you ATI card. You will then be able to install the fglrx driver, your system will ignore totally your Intel HD graphics.

That option is available for BIOS since v1.19 and up.