# installing my Graphic Card on ubuntu12.04

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavillion G6 series 1225, i5 laptop with Radeon HD 6470M switchable VGA. i installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but the VGA drivers don't work properly. I want to install drivers into the Ubuntu. But when I do it arrived error message like this:

> sorry, installation of this driver failed. Please have a look at the
>   log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

I found a solution in a link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450

It works for a few steps and then in the installation of the package of the AMD driver, a message pops up 'fatal error' and it redirects me to Ask Ubuntu to find a solution, please help me, I need to make it work.

Comment: no I have a ubuntu 12.04

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60121/support-on-hp-pavillion-g4-1004tx-with-intel-amd-hybrid-graphics

Comment: you should be fine with this : [solution]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513

Answer (score 1):

I successfuly installed the ATI drivers following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/218894/32413).

This answer explains:

- how to uninstall the driver that failed
- install the open source driver (it is a temporary step)
- download the last driver on ATI web site
- and install it

Answer (score 0):

I used these instructions by using a custom compiled driver by a good community member.  It's working for me on Ubuntu 12.10 with an HP envy with a radeon 7690, and maybe it could work for you

> sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrikos/xserver
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get -y upgrade
>
> sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-video-intel
>
> sudo apt-get -y install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
>
> sudo aticonfig --initial -f

Instructions were found at the end of this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450&page=66)